# Passing sensitive information from Python Flask to HTML5 LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am trying to run a flask application where I have to store sensitive information in the user's browser (localstorage) and fetch it later. The thing is, I have that sensitive information on the server side, and apparently localstorage can only be accessed on the client side via Javascript.

So my question is, what is the best and safest way to do that given my scenario?

Here is an example of what I was thinking...please tell me if this is bad and why, and any alternatives to this approach.

```
#This function gets the sensitive info from an AJAX request via the HTML page
@app.route("/sensitive_info/<string:sensitive_info>", methods=["POST"])
def save_sensitive_info(sensitive_info):
    db.save(sensitive_info)
    return redirect(url_for('inject_sensitive_info_to_local_storage'))

# This function creates an HTML page that injects the sensitive info using a javascript function with a jinja variable
@app.route("/sensitive_info")
def inject_sensitive_info_to_local_storage():
    sensitive_info = [RANDOM_SENSITIVE_INFORMATION]
    return render_template("index.html", sensitive_info=sensitive_info)
```

So as the comments describe, the second function puts the sensitive info into lcoal storage:

In the html...

```
localStorage.setItem('sensitive_info', {{sensitive_info}});
```

and for the first function, the html page would make an Ajax post to our flask sending the data:

```
$.ajax({url: '/sensitive_info' + localStorage.getItem("sensitive_info")), success: function (data) {console.log("Success");}});
```

Comment: [Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Storage_APIs)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use flask session to store information securely on the client side.

You should set the `SECRET_KEY` when you configure the flask app. The information stored in session on your client is encrypted, and can only be read if you know this secret key. Set your `SECRET_KEY` to a fairly long random number.

```
SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(24)
```

Then in your routine that gets the secret information you can add:

```
session['secret_info'] = secret_info.
```